# Regex to only match two asterisks

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm sorry if the question is unclear
I am trying to make a regular expression that replaces everything with `**` at the beginning and end with `"Test"` (for now at least.)

Currently this is my pattern:
`\*{2}[\w\s]+\*{2}`
This works so that strings like `**Car**`, `**123**`, `**This is a test**` get replaced with `"Test"`, except also for example `***Bird***` becomes `*Test*`.

So my question is if there is a way to make sure strings only get replaced with `"Test"` when there's exactly two `**` at beginning and end, no more (so `***Bird***` stays `***Bird***` and doesn't get replaced).

Comment: what about `**abc**def**`? does it get replaced to TestTest? Or just Test? How many occurrences do you expect in your text? What about `** abc ** def ** ghi ** jkl **`?

Comment: why? it starts with `**` and ends with `**`. what about `**abc**def**ghi**`?

Comment: `**abc**def**` becomes `Testdef**`, meanwhile `** abc ** def ** ghi ** jkl **` gets replaced by `Test def Test jkl **`

Comment: `**abc**def**ghi**` turns into `TestdefTest`

Comment: My question is: Why would it? `**abc**def**` meets your requirement: it starts and ends with exactly two asterisks. your requirement misses some conditions to make it unambiguous.

Comment: @Psi It looks like a straightforward requirement to me. Your overlapping use case seems to be out of scope for the OP's issue.

Comment: Because the expression is just `[\w\s]+`. It only looks for word characters and whitespaces, meanwhile `*` is neither. `**abc**def**` doesn't become `Test` because the two `**` in the middle are neither words nor whitespaces.

Comment: @nice_dev well, no. especially in the context of regular expressions, those requirements do matter. because regular expressions are _greedy _ by default, they will match the longest possible substring. and that would match `**abc**def**ghi**` rather than just `**abc**`. It’s a very important question

Comment: @Psi Your example is valid but as OP cleared, for `**abc**def**` becomes `Testdef**`, so now we don't need to have any non capturing groups in our regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In my opinion, you can have a lazy regex that does match the `*-chars-*` pattern in a way where it doesn't bother about how many `*` are there before and after.
- Use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to check with the captured groups and return `Test` accordingly if only 2 `*` before and after meet this condition. This way, your code is much more readable and simple.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$newText = preg_replace_callback(
    '/([*]+)[^*]+([*]+)/',
    function ($matches) {
        return strlen($matches[1]) == 2 && strlen($matches[2]) == 2 ? 'Test' : $matches[0];
    },
    $text
);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/3e5d0)

---

If you wish to keep the text inside `**` as is and make it bold, you can capture it in a group and surround it with bold tags.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$newText = preg_replace_callback(
        '/([*]+)([^*]+)([*]+)/',
        function ($matches) {
            return strlen($matches[1]) == 2 && strlen($matches[3]) == 2 ? '<b>' . $matches[2] . '</b>' : $matches[0];
        },
        $text
);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/5d8d31)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a handful of zero-length assertions. This is the regex that I suggest: `(?<!\*)\*{2}(?!\*).*?(?<!\*)(?<!\*)\*{2}(?!\*)` You can play with this [here](https://regex101.com/r/tF6m15/2).

Explanation:

- `(?<!\*)` A negative lookbehind: the match must not be preceded with a star character. It can be preceded with any other character, as well as with the line start. For the record, `^` is a well-known zero-length assertion.
- `\*{2}` - matches two stars
- `(?!\*)` - negative lookahead. This means that the next character must not be a star. However, this is a zero-length assertion, so the next character will not be matched.
- `.*?` - everything else - the star is for the non-greedy match. Not necessary, but I find it enhances the regex match. You can also group this if you want to do something with the match later.
- `(?<!\*)` - negative lookbehind - another zero-length assertion. It specifies that the last character must not be a star.
- `\*{2}` - two stars, to close the match
- `(?!\*)` - A negative lookahead: the match must not be followed by a star. It can be any other character, as well as the end of line. Btw, `$` is a well-known zero-length assertion.